# Durandal click call function from other file

Tags: javascript, jquery, knockout.js, durandal

I have a main file(periods.js), that is opening by a click-bind an custom dialog:

**periods.js**

```
[...]
            openAddFreeDayDialog = function () {
            var dialog = {viewUrl: 'views/addFreeDay'};
            app.showDialog(dialog);
        },

        addFreeDay = function () {
            var data = $('#addFreeDay').serializeArray();
        },
[...]
```

**periods.html**

```
[...]
<button type="button" class="btn btn-success btn-block" data-bind="click:$root.openAddFreeDayDialog"><i class="fa fa-plus-circle fa-lg"></i> new</button>
[...]
```

The function `openAddFreeDayDialog` open this modal:

**addFreeDay.html**

```
<div class="modal-content autoclose">
    <div class="modal-header">
        <h3 class="modal-title">freien Tag hinzufügen</h3>
        <small>Dauert der dieser freie Tag nur einen Tag  müssen Entdatum und Startdatum übereinstimmen</small>
    </div>
    <div class="modal-body">
        <form id="addFreeDay">
            <div class="form-group">
                <label for="dayName">Bezeichnung für diesen Tag </label>
                <input type="text" class="form-control" id="dayName">
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <label for="dayStartDate">Anfagsdatum des Tages </label>
                <input type="date" class="form-control" id="dayStartDate">
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <label for="dayEndDate">Enddatum des Tages </label>
                <input type="date" class="form-control" id="dayEndDate">
            </div>
        </form>
    </div>
    <div class="modal-footer">
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-success btn-lg btn-block" data-bind="click:$addFreeDay"><i class="fa fa-plus-circle fa-lg"></i>other new</button>
    </div>
</div>
```

I want to call in this dialog with a click-bind a other function of the main file:

```
<button type="button" class="btn btn-success btn-lg btn-block" data-bind="click:$addFreeDay"><i class="fa fa-plus-circle fa-lg"></i>other new</button>
```

I tried many thinks: `click:addFreeDay`, `click:addFreeDay`, `click:$root.addFreeDay`, `click:periods.addFreeDay` , `click:$periods.addFreeDay`, `click:$root.periods.addFreeDay`

Sometimes it gives me an error sometimes not. What do I wrong?

Answer (score 0):

Do you have a corresponding **periods.html** file as the view?

In the **periods.html** file, you would have your markup, including your `click` binding.  The viewModel behind that--the **periods.js** file--would contain the event handler for the click, which is where you would call your dialog.  Those two files together, in Durandal and Aurelia, comprise an MVVM unit.

Depending on your compositional structure, most likely you would access the function with `$data.addFreeDay.bind($data)` as the handler.  But it could just as easily be `$parent.addFreeDay.bind($parent)` or `$root.addFreeDay.bind($root)`, again, depending on your structure.

Comment: Thanks for your help, I tried all three and they give no error in the console, but the function didn't do anything. I edited the topic here and add some more code, maybe now is it easier to help me.

Comment: I still don't have sufficient code to help you.  It's hard to tell if your viewModels are singletons or instances.  If they're singletons, you need to make sure that you're revealing the functions you're trying to access.  If they're instances, you need to make sure you're returning a constructor function.  I can tell you that, in your periods.html file, you should change your click handler to `click: $data.openFreeDayDialog.bind($data)`.  Also, where is **addFreeDay.js**?

Comment: I have no addFreeDay.js because I think that it is not necessary. I know that this not will be a clean MVVM structure but the file would than only have one function. Here you an find the periods.js: http://pastebin.com/W2zR30vw and here the periods.html http://pastebin.com/pHMRvx9u

Comment: Yes, but that's your problem.  You can have views on their own, with no corresponding viewModel.  But the dialog functionality creates an isolated context.  Create an **addFreeDay.js** file, move your function to it, and then compose the two together in a dialog context.  The fact that there is, or may be, only one function is not really a sound criterion for determining whether to do a full MVVM.  At that point, you would simply need `click: addFreeDay` or `click: $data.addFreeDay.bind($data)`.